# emsdk not getting installed Web assembly

Tags: python, webassembly

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\emsdk\emsdk", line 2199, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\emsdk\emsdk", line 1853, in main
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1 or sys.argv[1] == 'help' or sys.argv[1] == '--help':
TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()

i am getting the  error while installing emsdk with the below command

emsdk install --build=Release sdk-incoming-64bit binaryen-master-64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the installation instructions?

https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/downloads.html

Perhaps you don't have the correct version of python installed?  Try using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, click on Settings and type in the search: "Manage Application Execution Aliases". Disable python.exe and python3.exe.
2. Okay, now create a folder where you want to clone github's Emscripten. Inside that folder type: git clone https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk.git --> If you have already cloned, skip this step.
3. cd emsdk
4. git pull --> Will update or say it's already up to date
5. call emsdk install latest latest
6. call emsdk activate latest
7. call emsdk_env.bat

The Emscripten SDK should now be installed.